# Get filtered data from API using axios `get` function

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, axios

I have a react App which call an Django API (DRF). On the front I want to apply some filters, so I want to get the data with this filters applied from the API and also with pagination. How can I do a request to the API that response only the filtered data?

My current view (`views.py`) class looks like

```
from .serializer import ExerciseSerializer
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination

class ExerciseView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ExerciseSerializer
    queryset = Exercise.objects.all()
    pagination_class = PaginateExercises
```

I am aware that I can write `queryset = Exercise.objects.all().filter(course="Precalculus")` and this will show only the objects with the `course` attribute equals to `Precalculus`, but then will always show this filter. I want to manage this filter in the API from the frontpage applying several filters at time.

I tried defining a `get_query_set`:

```
def get_queryset(self) -> QuerySet[Any]:
    course = self.kwargs['course']
    return Exercise.objects.all().filter(course=course)
```

but terminal says `KeyError: 'course'`. Also I tried defining a `get` method:

```
def get(self, request: HttpRequest, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> HttpResponse:
        course = self.kwargs['course']

        return HttpResponse(Exercise.objects.all().filter(course=course))
```

Didn't work. On the front I have an API file which I use to get the information from the API. This is the code

```
import axios from "axios";

const exerciseAPI = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:8000/exercises/api/exercise/",
});

export const getAllExercises = (
    pagenum = 1,
    course = "",
    lesson = "",
    topic = ""
) => {
    return exerciseAPI.get("/", {
        params: { page: pagenum, course: course, lesson: lesson, topic: topic },
    });
};
};
```

There is something I'm missing in the back (or front). To be more specific there is a way to get the params in the `views.py` as variables and then apply it as filters? Or there is a better way to solve this?

Comment: Assuming `request: HttpRequest` is the request from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/request-response then you should probably read the documentation on the QureyDict object. So use request.GET.items() probably.

Comment: To be clear, args and kwargs is not needed in your view, the data is in the request object.

Comment: Solved. I used `self.request.GET.get('course')` to get the parameter value on the `get_queryset()` method. Thanks!